# Huckel model of periodic systems

Tags: hamiltonian, linear-algebra

I have a polymer that is approximated by linear chain model. I need to solve the eigenvalue problem with such infinite dimensional hamiltonian matrix and ansatz $c_n = Asin(kna)$, where $k=\dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda}$. I have to show that eigenenergies are given by $E(k) = E_0 + 2Vcos(ka)$. I solved the problem with simple compound like ethene 2x2 hamiltonian so secular equation and first nearest neighbor approximation is clear for me, but what should I do with the infinite hamiltonian? I would appreciate any tips.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your matrix equations in terms of indices with
your ansatz that c_n is an eigenvector:
$$
\sum_m H_{nm} c_m = E c_n\,,
$$
and notice that for any given $n$ there are only 3 nonzero
terms
in the sum, m=n+1,n,n-1. Write them out and solve for E.
A possibly faster way is to use the ansatz $c_n=e^{ikna}$, which is what Bloch's theorem would have led you to, and notice that the states with $k$ and $-k$ are degenerate so
any linear combination like $\sin(kna)$ is an eigenstate.